# Usercontrol and Page Postback

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, asp.net-2.0

I have a page with three radio buttons and a calendar usercontrol. The radio buttons have autopostback and depending on which one you click it should change the calendar availabilities based on the selected index. The problem is that the page load of the calendar is executing first before the selected index change (where I am setting the needed id).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't initialize your Calendar-Control automatically in Page_Load. It should only be initialized through a public method. You could call this method `If Not Page.IsPostback` with default-settings and from your `SelectedIndexChanged` event-handler with the selected value(s) as parameter(s).